# Sorting/Deleting Duplicate Data and Outputting to CSV Correctly

Tags: python, list, csv, sorting, file-writing

I want to sort the data alphabetically, which was achieved with help below. After the data is sorted i want to go through and delete any duplicates, but i can't figure out how to do this. Once the data is sorted and duplicates are deleted i want to export it to a csv file.

To sum it up, i'm looking to

1. Deleting duplicates after sorting
2. Outputting to csv file correctly

Right now after i scrape the data and i print it out before writing it to a csv file it looks like this

```
['8 Mile', 'A Haunted House', 'Alien: Covenant', 'American Sniper', 'Baby Driver', 'Batman', 'Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice (Extended Cut)', 'Beauty and the Beast (2017)']
```

With my current code when it writes to my csv file it puts everything in the top row and each name into its own cell like it should. I can't figure out why it doesn't put it into multiple rows instead of just the one.

With the sample code i tried right below this paragraph when it writes to my csv file the output is in rows like it should be but there are spaces between the rows. Also instead of it being example, it writes e x a m p l e   with each letter in a different cell.

```
movielist2 = []
        for movie in movielist:
            [movielist2.append(list(list(movie)))]
        writer.writerows(movielist2)
```

I can't figure out why it wont print in multiple rows and all together with the change.

```
        all_images = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.border .gwt-Image')
        #for image in all_images[:5]: # first five elements
        for image in all_images:
            #print('image:', image.get_attribute('src'))
            #print('alt:', image.get_attribute('alt'))
            movienames = image.get_attribute('alt')

            #Add movie name to list
            movielist.append(movienames)

        #Scroll down the page to load more dynamic content
        for _ in range(1,6):
            ActionChains(browser).send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()

        time.sleep(5)

    #Sort movie name list and delete duplicates
    movielist = list(set(movielist))
    movielist.sort()

    print(movielist)
    #Write movie names to a csv file
    file = "Example2.csv"
    with open(file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
        #writer.writerows([movielist])

        movielist2 = []
        for movie in movielist:
            [movielist2.append(list(list(movie)))]
        writer.writerows(movielist2)
    print("Writing complete")
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Comment: Thanks, ill look this over before i post again!

Comment: The intent is for you to fix this question to meet the SO standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Removing duplicates

Before

```
#Sort movie name list
movielist.sort()
```

Add the line

```
movielist = list(set(movielist))
```

A set is like a list, except you're not allowed to have duplicates in a set, so converting your list to a set and back will remove all duplicates.

## The CSV Output

csvwriter.writerow takes a list of lists. The outer lists are for each of the rows and the inner list is for each column in that row. Right now the outer list only has one item in it -- `[movielist]`. And everything inside of movielist is the data for the various columns.

What you're going to want to do is instead of passing writerows.rows data that is in the form `[ ["title1", "title2", "title3", "etc."] ]`
You're going to want to pass it something more like this `[ ["title1"], ["title2"], ["title3"], ["etc."] ]`

*Edit 2:* This can be done like so:

```
movielist2 = []
for movie in movielist:
    movielist2.append([movie])
writer.writerows(movielist2)
```

*Edit 3:* Instead of doing the above, you could also change the line

```
#Add movie name to list
movielist.append(movienames)
```

to

```
#Add movie name to list
movielist.append([movienames])
```

And that should work as well. You just have to make sure that the movielist that gets passed into the writer.writerows() function is a list of lists, instead of a list.

Comment: first off thanks for the help with the duplicates, it seems to work flawlessly!

Comment: i understand whats going on now with my output, but how to a transition from "title1" to ["title1"]. I cant seem to get a way for that to work

Comment: You can use the list function to transition from having a string to a single-item list. I've updated my answer to show how you would go about doing this.

Comment: It printed them into rows like it should be each letter was put into its own column. Like this: E x a m p l e     It also it putting spaces between each row

Comment: What happens if you do [movielist2.append(list(list(movie)))] instead?

Comment: It does the exact same output, im going to edit my code above in case im implementing it wrong!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store the data as a set from the beginning so you don't have to remove the duplicates later?

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: This is just a side project, and also my one of my first times using python. I've done almost everything up to this point by myself except for one question yesterday. about how to use selenium to access the specific item i needed in html. Ive kept asking questions about csv output and how to do it because i still haven't been able to get it right.

Comment: Well this question has been answered, it'd help if you made another question to get more eyes on it.  IMHO.  :)

Comment: @ZacharyRW I tested it out, and using writer.writerows([["tmp1"],["tmp2"]]) works. Could you print out what is inside of your movielist right before you write it to a file.

Comment: Yes, this i what it outputs. ['8 Mile', 'A Haunted House', 'Alien: Covenant', 'American Sniper', 'Baby Driver', 'Batman', 'Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice (Extended Cut)']

Comment: I've updated my answer now. Instead of movielist2.append(list(movie)), it's movielist2.append([movie]).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and patience!!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it worked, and sorry for having given you some bad code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting your data using a keyword,just like in your example :

```
temp ="example|example|example"
temp_List = temp.split("|")
result=set(temp_List)
```

in result you will get a list, in which all the duplicates will be deleted. You can then access this list for putting it to csv file , row by row. Try it and let me know if you face any problem. Happy coding:)

Comment: Oh sorry, ill edit my question. The | was meant to indicate a new cell in the same row. How would you do it with that?